# Best parallel programming approach for this data migration task in Microsoft/.NET stack

Tags: .net, sql

I have SQL Server 2008 database with 2 tables:

- Table A has columns `ID (int), XmlDocument (xml`)
- Table B has columns `ID (int), PdfDocument (varbinary)`

I have some .NET code that can take the XmlDocument and convert into PDF. I have 1.3 million rows in Table A, and to convert all the rows sequentially would take 1.3 millions rows @ 1 row/sec = 15 days.

I want to approach that let's be do this in less than 2 hours. The problem seems to be a perfect case for parallelization. My question is what should I use to achieve this, and if any one has any good advice that has worked in the past. I have access to a virtual machine lab, and can potentially spin up several (5-6) virtual machines and this is a test database that I can copy wherever.

For example, should I do this in SQL (service broker or sql job for parallellism and calling a CLR proc for the conversion) or .NET (should I have a multiple processess on multiple machines or multiple threads in the same machine will get me pretty close)? What will be the bottle necks? Any suggestions about what strategies I should use to share work between threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a host of different solutions that could solve this problem but I will suggest something novel. Use the cloud.

Assuming the true bottleneck is the computing power to convert the Xml to a PDF then getting access to an environment with virtually unlimited scale out may prove the quickest way.

Answer (score 2):

The bottle neck is definitely going to be the conversion process, I generate dynamic PDFs in .NET all the time and most of my small 2-3 page documents can easily take a few seconds (5-8).  Any reason you can't pre-generate and store in a temp table, so all you have to do is move via SQL when your ready?  Also, make sure you generate efficient (size optimized) PDFs since 1.3 million PDF's could easily consume many gigabytes of storage.

Comment: Yes, I plan to pre-generate, but we may have to pre-generate multiple times based on if QA finds bugs in the generation process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this as a .net console app rather then a SQL type job because it's a lot easier to take a console program and simply run it on a bunch of client machines that aren't in use at the moment. Assuming the documents have some kind of primary key, you would figure out how many client computers you have to run the app and then divide the primary keys between them. If you've got four, each app gets a split of the keys for approximately 1/4 of the load. You can pass what key range to work with using a variety of methods, depending on what the key looks like.

In the app itself you'd select the records you're going to work with, then use either Parallel Linq or a Parallel foreach loop to process the records for that client. Both those are pretty easy parallel constructs to work with, they create threads to do what's inside the loop without needing to explicitly deal with it (the framework handles the threads for you).

At that point it's just a matter of throwing enough clients at it to finish within your timeframe.